# Element-relative CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, selectors-api

Is there a way to shorten these types of lines by using CSS selectors and jQuery?

```
$(element).parent('tr').parent('tbody').parent('table')

$(element).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td')
```

It is basically: "get me the **direct** parent/children if any"

I need 100% equal selectors.

UPDATE:

`closest('table)` does not work: can return the element itself AND may find not direct parents
`find('td')` does not work: as I need only the direct children; there might be plenty of them in the subtree below

Comment: Add `HTML` also or create `jsfiddle`

Comment: I would like to see HTML-agnostic selectors. The given chains of parent/children calls are correct. I just want to see them in a more concise way.

Comment: jQuery and CSS selectors are separate things. Not everything that is possible with a jQuery selector is possible with a CSS selector.

Comment: Do you refer to the '> ' selector from @ArunPJohny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the first ancestor mathcing the given selector

```
element.parent('tr').parent('tbody').parent('table') -> $(element).parent('tr').closest('table')
```

In the below case use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) with [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
element.children('tbody').children('tr').children('td') -> element.find('> tbody > tr > td')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw.. I did not know one can use '>' at the beginning to signify 'start by the given element'. Since closest is not correct, if you would change that, I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @SvenR.Kunze in that case you can use `element.parent().closest('table')` so that it will not find the element itself, but will return one of its ancestors

Comment: Not quite. This would mean I would get the first parent table. But I need the structure above: the first DIRECT parent. Not the first of any parents that might match.

Comment: Every element except the root element can only have exactly one parent (the root element has none). So either the element's parent matches the selector, or it doesn't.

Comment: Let's assume the following structure of the HTML: table > tbody > tr > td > div > div > div <<< here I do not want to get the table element given element = third div

Comment: @SvenR.Kunze If you wan to make such tight selection rule then `$(element).parent('tr').parent('tbody').parent('table')` will be the way to go... or best `$(element).parent('tr').closest('table')` - because we can assume `tbody` will be present

Comment: Alright. Thanks, I will mark your answer as accepted, if you could change that, too. Just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Btw. is using '>' at the beginning of find a jQuery extension or is that vanilla CSS?

Comment: @SvenR.Kunze querySelector API does not allow it if that is what you are asking

Comment: Alright. That is what I wanted to know. So, it is a jQuery-convenience functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest` to get the closest `ancestor`:

```
element.closest('table') // element.parent('tr').parent('tbody').parent('table')
```

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

and `find` to search down the `DOM` tree:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
element.find('td') // element.children('tbody').children('tr').children('td')
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest` to move up to the closest matching element. Also, use `find` to search into the given element (note that find will get all the matching elements going down to all the existing DOM tree layers)

```
element.closest('table');
element.find('td');
```